# PHP multidimentional Array syntax not clear

Tags: php, arrays

I'm using RIPS PHP scanner. In one of the php files it has a line as bellow:

$F_XSS = array('echo' => array(array(0), $F_SECURING_XSS), ......)

what is the meaning of  "**array(array(0)**" above?

Comment: It... means "an array whose first element is an array containing the element `0`"... It literally means what it says, there's no hidden magic here. Since PHP 5.4 you could write it as `["echo" => [ [0], $F_SECURING_XSS], ...]`

Comment: Please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help ) it will be useful to lift your content quality up

Comment: @Niet Thank you! It helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

That mean that the array 'echo' will have a value an array with a value (int) 0

**PHP**

```
[
     'echo' =>
         [
              [
                 0
              ],
              $F_SECURING_XSS
         ],
      ....
  ]
```

Comment: Thank you! It helped me a lot.